# error redirect url using Angular and Html

Tags: angular

i need to refresh my table or actual url before the update register, i have this redirect but don´t works, please help :C

component .ts

```
  updateDoctor = () => {
    this.dataService.updateDoctor(this.selectedDoctor).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.selectedDoctor = data;
        this.btnClose.nativeElement.click()
        this.redirect();
      },
      error => {
        alert('Error al Actualizar doctor');
      }
    );
  }
}
  redirect() {
        this.router.navigate(['./doctores'])
    }
```

component .html

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="updateDoctor()">Guardar Cambios</button>
```

Comment: Have tried after removing dot from route navigate. Follow like https://angular.io/guide/router.     this.router.navigate(['/doctores'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with:

```
  redirect() {
    this.router.navigate(['../doctores'])
}
```

and check your console in order to see what kind of error is showing up, if you paste an image about i can help you

Comment: thnx , i fix with ... this.btnClose.nativeElement.click(location.reload())

Comment: reload is not too clean, if you want to update the values in your view, try to make al gets you make onInit method